# Php auto increment columns based on mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have mysql table performance(id,name,type,value,date) and I am using dynamic query like

```
SELECT performance.name,
       performance.type,
       Coalesce(Sum((CASE
                         WHEN (performance.date = '2017-11-02') THEN performance.value
                     END)), 0) AS "2-Nov"
FROM performance
WHERE performance.type = 'Max'
GROUP BY performance.name,
         performance.type
```

to get datewise column output based on start date and end date.
I am printing mysql query result on php page using mysql_fetch_array function     `echo "<td>" . $row['2-Nov(In)'] . "</td>";` and its woring fine with static entries.
I want add auto increment columns on my php code based on dynamic mysql query so that number of $row[] will change inside array as per start date and end date.
eg :

```
`echo "<td>" . $row['2-Nov(In)'] . "</td>";
`echo "<td>" . $row['3-Nov(In)'] . "</td>";`
`echo "<td>" . $row['4-Nov(In)'] . "</td>";` etc.
```

My query sample output

```
name                      | type | 2-Nov |
+-----------------------------------------+
| Name1                     | Max  | 72.97 |
| Name2                     | Max  |  34.2 |
| Name3                     | Max  | 15.14 |
| Name4                     | Max  | 11.38 |
+-----------------------------------------+-
```

I am using below codes to print my query output

```
$sql = "$a $b $d $d";
$result = @mysql_query($sql,$connection) or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row[name] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row[type] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['2-Nov(In)'] . "</td>"; <-- start date
echo "<td>" . $row['3-Nov(In)'] . "</td>";  $row auto increase/decrease
echo "<td>" . $row['4-Nov(In)'] . "</td>";  based on start and end date
echo "<td>" . $row['5-Nov(In)'] . "</td>"; <-- end date
echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Are you looking to auto-increment the IDs of each row?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @MegaColorBoy : No, I want to add/remove $row[$output] count based on start and end date.

Comment: I finally resolved the issue ...